# Bootstrap 4 Page Layout For Mobile/Desktop Two Sidebars Hidden on Mobile with Header

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I usually do back-end design with a little bit of front end, but this particular page has been fighting me for the last few hours.

What I've put together looks absolutely terrible on mobile and doesn't really work well on desktop - I'm relatively new to Bootstrap 4 and with flex boxes it doesn't seem like this should be too complicated.

I'd really appreciate any help with this! Thank you :)

I'd like to keep the entire thing visible on one page - with mobile landscape/portrait just showing the content and box/button.

This is what I'm going for:

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not completely done with it, but here's the gist of it.

CSS:

```
body { 
    padding-top:54px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#content {
    margin-top: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100vh - 104px);
}
#page-wrapper {
    height: calc(100vh - 54px);
}
```

Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a id="HeaderLink" class="nav-link btn-raised">
                <span id="HeaderLinkSpan">
                    App Name
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-menu-right text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-raised" type="button"
                id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown:
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu center-dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 3</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="?logout">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<% include ../partials/navheader.ejs %>
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-2" id="LeftSidebar" style="background-color:blue">
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="row" id="content">
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters" style="height:40px;padding-top:7px;">
          <div class="col-10 no-gutters">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2" id="RightSidebar" style="background-color:greenyellow">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Results:

[image: Results]